# Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField with the label on the inside and golden glow around the outline when selected

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a TextField like in the image using Jetpack Compose.
So far no luck in finding a easy way.
The label must stay inside the outline, if I use OutlinedTextField there is no way to customise that. If I use the TextField which has the label on the inside there is no outline when selected, just the line below the textfield.
Also I need to add a shadow/glow effect with a custom color, here seen in gold.
I'm stumped..
Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Can you just put the textField on top of a golden box with a shadow effect, just slightly smaller? Make the golden box visible when selected only.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a Row with a `Modifier.drawBehind` that uses native paint to draw blur with color as [in this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Badge/master/screenshots/badge.gif), the one with pink background has blur with same background color for shadow for instance, you can check the code for drawing colored blur [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Badge/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/composebadge/MaterialShadow.kt).

```
                   val myColor = color
                       .copy(alpha = shadow.alpha)
                       .toArgb()

                   val transparent = color
                       .copy(alpha = 0f)
                       .toArgb()

                   frameworkPaint.color = transparent

                   frameworkPaint.setShadowLayer(
                       radius,
                       dx,
                       dy,
                       myColor
                   )

                 it.drawRoundRect(
                           //...
                           paint = paint
                       )
```

It draws a shape behind you can draw a shape with stroke.

For the label and input create a `Column` with `Modifier.weight()` to use space inside row other than space reserved for Icon with close image.

Instead of TextField you can use a `BasicTextfield` which doesn't have default padding, however you can achieve the same thing with `TextField` too, but you will need to set colors to transparent to remove indicator line, it has some default padding you might not want to have.

```
        TextField(
    
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can archive like this by using TextFiled surround with Box

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(vertical = 2.dp)
        .border(
            1.dp,
            if (isError) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.errorBg else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.loginBorderColor,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        )
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            onValueChange(it)
        },
        colors = worksTextFieldColors(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(0.dp),
        label = {
            Text(
                text = hint, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.blue1,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.placeholder
            )
        },
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.loginEntryText.copy(
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.commonTxt
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            autoCorrect = false, imeAction = ImeAction.Next, keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
        )
    )
}
```